# Should I edit a Question once the Answer has been accepted?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, answers

My answer to [**this question**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152468/take-data-from-website-and-save-it-in-office/152496#152496) was accepted. However I don't believe the question itself will be useful to others in its current state. Is it appropriate to edit a question to be more meaningful to others after the answer has been accepted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edits can always be reverted.  If it's obvious you're doing it with good intentions, I see no problems with it.

I recently edited a question title with an accepted answer.  [Here's my example.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151394/is-a-non-trivial-plug-in-for-some-application-considered-an-app)

I edited the title from something referencing blender plug-ins to something more generic.

Answer (score 4):

**Absolutely**. A more general answer is better than a narrower one most of the time. If you need to edit the question to correspondingly be a little more generalized, so be it.

Hijacking a question to fit a pre-fabricated answer is what would be beyond the pale.

Answer (score 0):

**Another point**: Not such a way that, The Accepted answer becomes invalid. It will be harmful for the site

Comment: Thanks, that was not my intention as you see from the question above.  I try to answer questions resonsibly in alignment with the rules and ethics of the site and come to Meta when I am unsure. I ONLY answer questions when I believe my answers will benefit others.

Comment: +1. My answer was intended for future users who will see this. I have faith in you